# I'm trying to copy a range of data from one worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel, copy, excel-2013

When I tried to copy sheet1 of workbook1 to sheet2 of workbook2 it doesn't show anything on sheet2 except the copy selection frame. If I comment out Activeworkbook.Close. the workbook1 is open and the adequate sheet as well. But not only it is not copying, but when I press control paste it actually paste the sheet2 to itself. So I tried Range(cells(2,1), Cells(lastrow,lastcolumn)).Select without closing the workbook I want to copy to verify if it would at least select the range needed but it returns me a runt time error '1004' . If anyone see where my mistake is please help. thank you

```
Dim directory As String, FileName As String
Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long
Dim erow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "C:\Users\Documents\file1\"
FileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

'Open the Excel file
Workbooks.Open (directory & FileName)

'Select the worksheet and range of the worksheet to be copied
Worksheets("Luminaire Summary").Select
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy
'ActiveWorkbook.Close
erow = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))
```

I tried writing a shorter code after some advice but I'm still not getting any copied information from workbook1 sheet1 to workbook2 sheet2. Here is my last attempt  with no success

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim directory As String, FileName As String, total As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long  
directory = "C:\Users\Documents\"
FileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")       
Workbooks.Open (directory & FileName)    
Worksheets("Luminaire Summary").Select
UsedRange.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: I meant to say Range(cells(2,1), Cells(lastrow,lastcolumn)).Select

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify by using UsedRange

```
Worksheets("Luminaire Summary").Select
UsedRange.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial <-- 'or however you're determiing which cell to paste to
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. I replaced my code to yours just to see the output but it gives me a Run-time error '9' caused by the very last line Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Comment: another thing is that I cannot open the new work book and select the UsedRange space, which worries me a bit. For the simple reason that if it doesn't select the UsedRange is it going to be able to copy it as well?